# checking the web Authentication services in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

friend 
I am trying so much but I didn't get any solution 
  if  he or she enter their  username and password then i want cheek there value from webserver database.
If his username and password is much there only after then he will use the application .
other then that he doesn't have permission use this application.

Comment: do you have web service for authentication?

Comment: yes i have web service authentication i dont know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:-

```
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loginkey=%@&Password=%@&DeviceCode=%@&Firmware=%@&IMEI=%@",txtUserName.text,txtPassword.text,model,sysver,udid];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://191.16.0.6:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Login"]]; //add your web service url here
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which includes simple methods for basic HTTP authentication.